# How to place an HTML element over another using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a slider that I want to place an small icon over it using HTML and CSS, but both are position absolute and the slider is hiding the icon.

The CSS code for the icon is this:

```
#nav {  
    position:absolute;
    left: 49%;
    top: 89%;
}
```

Note that when I remove the slider from the javascript file, it shows the icon as I want but the sliders stop, so how can the icon get placed over the slider

Comment: give the slider a z-index and the icon a higher z-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `z-index` for this nav icon. Update your CSS like below.

```
#nav {  
position:absolute;
left: 49%;
top: 89%;
z-index:2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need-
http://jsfiddle.net/LUQjb/3/

HTML-

```
<div class="outerdiv">
<div class="youricon">
</div></div>
```

CSS-

```
.outerdiv{  
    position:relative;  
    width:400px;  
    height:400px;  
    background-color:black;  
}  

.youricon{  
    position:absolute;  
    width:200px;  
    height:200px;  
    background-color:red;  
    top:50px;  
    left:50px;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sliders having predefined z-index property. So you need to add higher z-index property to your icon.

```
#nav {  
    position:absolute;
    left: 49%;
    top: 89%;
    z-index:/* As per you requirment */;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply more Z-index to your small icon more than your slider image!

```
.slider{
 z-index: 100; }

.small-icon{ z-index: 200; }
```

Its all trick of Z-index!